# Let $F$ be field. Show that in $F[x]$ a prime ideal is a maximal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $F$ be field. Show that in $F[x]$ a prime ideal is a maximal ideal.

---

can someone help me please to tackle this problem.thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe you want to say that **non-zero** prime ideals are maximal.

Answer (score 6):

What is important here is that $F[x]$ is a PID.

Let $P$ be a prime ideal in $F[x]$, $P\neq (0)$. Write $P=(p)$.

Suppose that $Q$ is an ideal of $F[x]$ such that $P\subsetneq Q$. Write $Q=(q)$.

Now $p\in Q$, and so $p=aq$ for some $a$. Since $P$ is prime and $p=aq\in P$, we must have either $a\in P$ or $q\in P$; but $q\notin P$, and therefore $a\in P$.

Since $a\in P=(p)$, we can write $a=bp$ for some $b$. Then we have $p=aq=bpq$, or $p(1-bq)=0$. But, since $F[x]$ is an integral domain, and $p\neq 0$, we must have $bq=1$. But, this shows that $q$ is a unit, and so $Q=(q)=F[x]$.

So, if $P$ is a prime ideal and $P\subsetneq Q$, then $Q=F[x]$; hence $P$ is maximal.

Answer (score 2):

Another sort of approach:

Let $R=F[x]$ and suppose you are modding out by the nontrivial ideal $I=(f(x))$. Recall that $R/I$ is going to be finite dimensional over $F$, since the quotient reduces things from $R$ to have degree less than $deg(f)$. Consequently, $R/I$ is an Artinian ring.

But $R/I$ is also a domain, if $I$ is prime. However, an Artinian domain is a field, and so $I$ must be maximal.

Answer (score 1):

We must assume $P$ is nonzero.

Let $P$ be a prime ideal in $F[x]$. There is a theorem that a polynomial ring over a field is a PID, so $F[x]$ is a PID, and $P$ is generated by a single polynomial $g(x)$. Since $P$ is prime, $g(x)$ must be irreducible. Then the gcd of $g(x)$ and any polynomial that is not a multiple of $g(x)$ is $1$, so using the Bezout relation, you can invert any element of $F[x]/(g(x))$. So it is a field.

This is kind of sketchy. Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: what is Bezout relation?I have no idea about it.

Comment: @user82544 Do you recall that when $f$ and $g$ are coprime polynomials, you can find polynomials $p$ and $q$ with $fp+gq=1$? This is called a Bézout relation. You get it by using the GCD algorithm in reverse. (Go to the Wikipedia page on Bézout's theorem if this is unclear.)

Comment: o, I know this result but does know that this is called Bézout relation.Thanks a lot

Comment: Could the person who downvoted please explain why?